# Frame animation in Android?

Tags: android, animation, event-handling, effects

I am using frame animation for displaying some images. But it's working only in a button action. I want to call this function when the program starts. How can I achieve this with out a button?

I use the following code for the animation:

```java
public class FrameAnimationActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.setupButton();
    }
    private void setupButton(){
        Button b = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.startFAButtonId);
        b.setOnClickListener(
          new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                parentButtonClicked(v);
            }
          });
    }
    private void parentButtonClicked(View v){
        animate();
    }
    private void animate(){
        ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imgView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
        imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.frame_animation);
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imgView.getBackground();
        if (frameAnimation.isRunning()){
            frameAnimation.stop();
        }
        else{
            frameAnimation.stop();
            frameAnimation.start();
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/colored-ball1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/colored-ball2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/colored-ball3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/colored-ball4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/colored-ball5" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/colored-ball6" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/colored-ball7" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/colored-ball8" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

Comment: maybe you should check out the API demos, it comes in the examples of ur SDK. Had been a big help to me when I was a noob, and even now..

Comment: @ Shouvik :I got this code from API demos,but its not working out side the button action

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the Android's Documentation, you can found the following:

"It's important to note that the start() method called on the AnimationDrawable cannot be called during the onCreate() method of your Activity, because the AnimationDrawable is not yet fully attached to the window. If you want to play the animation immediately, without requiring interaction, then you might want to call it from the onWindowFocusChanged() method in your Activity, which will get called when Android brings your window into focus."

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

When you click on your button, the only thing that happens is the `animate()` method is called. Have you tried placing

```
animate();
```

inside of `onCreate()` and removing it from `parentButtonClicked(View v)` so that it calls animate when the activity is created, rather than when the button is pressed? Don't see why that wouldn't work for you.

Then you'll also have a useless button. :)